# Need to add empty Column in Spotfire Table Chart

Tags: spotfire

I need to add few column headers in Table chart in Spotfire. Typically some calculated/transformation are added for the creation of new column. i just need to create the column with a name and keep it empty since the space will be used to fill data after the report has been printed. Any expression to make the column empty is also fine but want to know whether an empty column can be added

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can add a new calculated column with a formula of `""` or `NULL` to make it empty